# Upgraded to 16.04, can't start Apache - Invalid command 'AssignUserID', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, apache2

As I was upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, I noticed that it removed `libapache-mpm-itk`.  After the upgrade, I ran `apache2ctl configtest` to see if it would pass.

The first error I encountered "cannot load libphp5.so" and so I purged it and installed libphp, which installed php7.  So far so good.

The next error was expected:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nsc.local.conf: Invalid command 'AssignUserID', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Note that I had been successfully using the mpm before upgrading.

So, the next logical thing to do is install the Apache 2 ITK MPM:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk`

but... it didn't change anything.  I still get the same error.  Any ideas where to go from here?

---

FYI info:

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Fetched 204 kB in 0s (373 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mpm-itk is already the newest version (2.4.7-04-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


$ ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
access_compat.load  autoindex.load  mpm_prefork.conf  proxy.load
alias.conf          deflate.conf    mpm_prefork.load  rewrite.load
alias.load          deflate.load    negotiation.conf  setenvif.conf
auth_basic.load     dir.conf        negotiation.load  setenvif.load
authn_core.load     dir.load        php7.0.conf       socache_shmcb.load
authn_file.load     env.load        php7.0.load       ssl.conf
authz_core.load     filter.load     proxy.conf        ssl.load
authz_host.load     headers.load    proxy_html.conf   status.conf
authz_user.load     mime.conf       proxy_html.load   status.load
autoindex.conf      mime.load       proxy_http.load   xml2enc.load
```

Comment: Do you see the module in the output of `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`?

Comment: post updated with output

Comment: Your question helped me. I had `sudo a2enmod mpm_itk` down, but forgot all about `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to have `mpm_itk.load` in your mods-enabled folder, which most likely indicates it's not loaded.

```
sudo a2enmod mpm_itk
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Bingo!  I got the following warnings:

    $ sudo a2enmod mpm_itk
    Considering dependency mpm_prefork for mpm_itk:
    Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
    Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
    Module mpm_prefork already enabled
    Enabling module mpm_itk.

But, that took care of the problem.